# page redirect problem in react, react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, history

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Message from "../../components/Message/Message";
import Loader from "../../components/Loader/Loader";
import { login } from "../../actions/userActions";

export default function Login({ history }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { loading, error, userInfo } = userLogin;

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));

    if (userInfo) {
      if (userInfo.isAdmin) {
        history.push("/admin/dashboard");
      } else {
        history.push("/");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-wrapper">
      <div className="container py-5">
        <div className="login-form p-5 rounded-2">
          <h2 className="pb-3 text-center">Sign In</h2>
          {error && <Message className="alert alert-danger">{error}</Message>}
          {loading && <Loader />}
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label for="email" className="form-label">
                Email address
              </label>
              <input
                type="email"
                value={email}
                className="form-control"
                id="email"
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="password" className="form-label">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                value={password}
                id="password"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="d-grid ">
              <button className="btn  btn-submit p-2" type="submit">
                CONTINUE
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between py-3">
              <p className="">
                New User?
                <Link to="/register" className="ms-1">
                  Signup
                </Link>
              </p>
              <a href="e">Forgot your password</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After complete successful login and if a user is an admin I want to show `/admin/dashboard` in url. But it still showing the `/login` URL. Or user is not an admin I want to show the home page. it's working fine for a normal user. But for the admin URL is not update.

Note: After submitting the login form I store userInfo in localstorage. Then I get localstorage data for checking if user admin or not.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: provide your react code by codesandbox.io will make us help you faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect on your call back action in `Login`.

Example :

```
if (userInfo) {
  if (userInfo.isAdmin) {
    history.push("/admin/dashboard");
  } else {
    history.push("/");
  }
}
```

In submitHandler After `dispatch(login(email, password));` they not wait for the action complate and `userInfo. isAdmin` is still not available so It's not redirect to the `/admin/dashboard` page.

You can use the `history` object in your action and do that.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes /> // Your all routes
      </Router>
  );
};
```

Now you can use history on your action.

```
import { history } from './app';

const login = () => { 
 // do API stuff
 history.push('/somewhere');

 history.push({
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  search: '?some=search-string',
  hash: '#howdy',
  state: {
   [userDefined]: true
   }
 });
};
```

Or you can listen to the userInfo in `useEffect` hooks and do that.

```
       useEffect(() => {
            if (userInfo.isAdmin) {
               history.push("/admin/dashboard");
            } else {
               history.push("/");
            }
        }, [userInfo?.isAdmin]);
```

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Could you please show your code how you intigrated

Comment: https://gist.github.com/soykot2910/b05693b4bbbf875ab59aab6f56d8d065 I upload my code in this gist.

Comment: You need to move history.push()  code in import { login } from "../../actions/userActions"; file.

In userActions import { history } from './app'; and use `history`.

Remove `if (userInfo) {
      if (userInfo.isAdmin) {
        history.push("/admin/dashboard");
      } else {
        history.push("/");
      }
    }` from submitHandler action.

Comment: Edi the answer added one more way to do this. Please check and try.

Comment: I am confused. I added my userAction.js in my gist. Could you please check the file?  where I place the code.

Comment: After line no 18 you place your history.push() code. Check data conditions from data object.

import { history } from './Admin';

Comment: if i used  if (userInfo) {
      if (userInfo.isAdmin) {
        history.push("/admin/dashboard");
      } else {
        history.push("/");
      }
    }   I got ar error unexpected token  gist: https://gist.github.com/soykot2910/b05693b4bbbf875ab59aab6f56d8d065/edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237211/discussion-between-asif-vora-and-soykot2910).